# Remember the last chosen input after submit in smarty

Tags: php, date, input, smarty

I have a website in php and smarty.And there are 2 labels with input where you can input date from calendar. After clicking Submit and refreshing website I want to remember the last chosen date in this specific label and I don't know how to do it in smarty.

this is code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                <label for="DateFrom">Date from</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                    <input class="text-box single-line form-control date" id="DateFrom" name="DateFrom" type="datetime"
                           value="{$date}">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the date in the session, then retrieve it when the page reloads:

E.g

- Initial page load - user chooses a date and submits.
- POST handler stores the date in a session variable.
- Second page load, check the session variable, get the date, then use it in the form.

Alternatively, you could use javascript to store the date in sessionStorage BEFORE the form is posted, and then use javascript to fetch from sessionStorage and populate after the page is reloaded.

Both solutions follow the same principles - store the data somewhere and retrieve it afterwards.